# List-Search with recursion by using list library

Tags: c++, list, recursion

```
int listRecSearch(list<int>list, const int data)
{
  if (list.empty())
  {
    cout << "The number is not in the list, try again..." << endl;
    return -1;
  }
  else if (list.back() == data)
  {
//    cout << "list.size(): " << list.size() << endl;
    list.pop_back();//I needed the index begins from 0 instead of 1
    return list.size();
  }
  else
  {
//    cout << "list.back(): " << list.back() << endl;
    list.pop_back();
    listRecSearch(list, data);
  }
}

//funtion used
int main()
{
 list<int>list = listGenerator(size);//generate a list with 20 random numbers.
 cout << "Specify the element to be searched for: ";
 cin >> data;
 int position = listRecSearch(list, data);
 if (position > -1)
    cout << "\nFind the element at position: " << position << endl;
}
```

The function `listRecSearch` was able to display correct `list.size()` value and correct pop_back values. But once it returned, it always return a garbage value. I figured there were steps were still went through after return, but I can't see where and how.

Comment: There exists a code path which does not return a value. `listRecSearch(list, data);` should become `return listRecSearch(list, data);`

Comment: I just fixed it, i was changing things around.

Comment: My comment is still valid after you edited. And I have edited the comment to pinpoint the most likely source of the issue. :)

Comment: I am surprised that the compiler did not complain about it. Maybe you should change the compiler flags that you are using. I have added the answer as well, if it resolved your issue then please accept it.

Comment: @ZFeng - Why not just use `std::find()`?  `std::find(list.begin(), list.end(), data);`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie because I need the position of the item, not just find it. :)

Comment: @bialpio I am using g++ compiler, next time I will use VS2013 to try it!

Comment: g++ with -Wall -Werror should complain about this. Or -pedantic.

Comment: @ZFeng - You *can* get the position using `std::find`.  You should have asked that.  `list<int> it = std::find(myList.begin(), myList.end(), data); if ( it != myList.end()) { return std::distance(myList.begin(), it); else return -1;`

Comment: @ZFeng - So basically, std::find returns an iterator to the position, and std::distance tells you how many items are between the starting iterator and the found iterator.  All simply done without recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exists a code path which does not return a value. `listRecSearch(list, data);` should become `return listRecSearch(list, data);`.